# Modelo de Página não aparece - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Criei um modelo de template de página no Wordpress para o site que estou fazendo. Porém após abrir uma página já criada a opção para selecionar o modelo criado não aparece. Poderiam me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Criei um arquivo chamado paginageral.php de acordo com as instruções do codex

```html
<?php  
/*
Template Name: Página Geral
*/ 
 ?>
 <?php get_header(); ?>
 <div class="conteudo">
 <main>
  <section class="meio container">
    <div class="noticias">    
      <p>Esta é a estrutura de paginas gerais</p>
    </div>
  </section>
 </main> 
</div> 
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa de um arquivo index.php no tema para funcionar essa função, mesmo que o arquivo index esteja vazio

Comment: Obrigado!! funcionou